# Можно ли подключить к компьютеру из интернета без внешнего IP?

Tags: сеть, http, ip, tcp-ip, nat

Провайдер Akado внешний IP  46.39.43.2, внутренний IP-адрес 10.5.23.64 (цифры немного изменены, но не суть), локальный IP-адрес 192.168.1.56. Можно ли как-нибудь подключиться к компьютеру из интернета (чтобы получить доступ к своим папкам, файлам и т.д.)? Слышал, что без внешнего IP нельзя, но как тогда работает TeamViewer, он же тоже вроде без внешнего IP, но ничего, подключает как-то?

Comment: Можете попробовать подключаться через VPN

Comment: У TeamViewer оба компьютера должны быть подключены к их серверу. Обмен данными идет через него. Можно в сторону динамического днс посмотреть https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+dns Большинство роутеров может его поддерживать через доступные сервисы из инета.